# SQL Query: Most frequent value in joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a SQL query where I want to join two tables on the most frequent occurrence of one field based on the most frequent occurrence of another.

There is a restaurant table of specific restaurants I want to get the most frequent order from. 
These items can be ordered by multiple different people at the same restaurant. I want to get the result for the most frequent item at each restaurant and of that item, I want the most frequent person who requests it.

```
Table Restaurants  
Restaurant
=======
R1
R2 

Table Orders
Item    RequestedBy    Restaurant     Date
==========================================
B1          A           R1             123
B1          B           R1             234
B2          C           R2             456
B1          A           R1             567
```

What I want,

```
Restaurant  Item   RequestedBy
============================
 R1          B1        A
 R2          B2        C
```

I currently have the below script:

```
SELECT Restaurants.Restaurant, Orders.Item, Orders.RequestedBy
FROM Restaurants 

LEFT JOIN (Select Restaurant, Item, RequestedBy
From [Orders] T1
Where Item=  
(Select TOP 1 Item
    from [Orders] T2
    where T1. Restaurant = T2. Restaurant
    group by Item
    order by count(Item) desc
)
group by Restaurant, Item, RequestedBy) Orders

ON  Restaurants.Restaurant = Orders.Restaurant
```

This currently returns data such as:

```
 Restaurant  Item   RequestedBy
 ===========================
 R1           B1        A
 R1           B1        B
 R2           B2        C
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: I can not comprehend how you expect to get `R2          B1        B` with only  `B2          C           R2             456` given for R2.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you actually need to join to the `restaurant` table? It seems like you could get all the information you need from the `orders` table alone.

Comment: @bummi oops sorry about that. Edited the question to fix that!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the given Orders table has some not fitting data and the request would be as described to find then

'to get the result for the most frequent item at each restaurant' 
and in a second step to

'I want the most frequent person who requests it'

I would recommend to keep it stupid simple and to split the task in Views, e.g.

```
Create View V_OrdersPerRestaurant_Item as
Select Restaurant,Item, COUNT(*) as Orders
from [dbo].[orders]
group by Restaurant,Item


Create View V_MaxSelectItemPerRestaurant as
Select * from V_OrdersPerRestaurant_Item ov
where Orders = (Select Max(Orders) from V_OrdersPerRestaurant_Item where  ov.Restaurant=Restaurant)


Create View V_MaxSelectItemPerRestaurantAndRequestedBy as
Select ms.Item,ms.Restaurant,o.RequestedBy,Count(*) as Requests from V_MaxSelectItemPerRestaurant ms
join [dbo].[orders] o on ms.Item=o.Item and ms.Restaurant=o.Restaurant
group by ms.Item,ms.Restaurant,o.RequestedBy
```

Which should allow to get the expected result by:

```
Select * from  V_MaxSelectItemPerRestaurantAndRequestedBy ov
where Requests=(Select max(Requests) from V_MaxSelectItemPerRestaurantAndRequestedBy iv where iv.Item=ov.Item and ov.Restaurant=iv.Restaurant)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest approach is to use `apply`:

```
select r.restaurant, ri.item, rir.requestedby
from restaurant r cross apply
     (select top (1) o.item, count(*) as cnt
      from orders o
      where o.restaurant = r.restaurant
      order by count(*) desc
     ) ri cross apply
     (select top (1) o2.requrestedby, count(*) as cnt
      from orders o2
      where o2.restaurant = r.restaurant and
            o2.item = r.item
      order by count(*) desc
     ) rir;
```

Another method that works is `order by` with window functions:

```
select top (1) with ties restaurant, item, requestedby
from (select o.restaurant, o.item, o.requestedby,
             count(*) as rir_cnt,
             sum(count(*)) over (partition by o.restaurant, o.item) as ri_cnt
      from orders o
      group by o.restaurant, o.item, o.requestedby
     ) rir
order by row_number() over (partition by restaurant order by ri_cnt desc),
         row_number() over (partition by restaurant, item order by rir_cnt desc);
```